# Completely remove windows 7 ult x64 w/o live CD?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows, uninstall

Finally I want to ditch windows completely but after googling I found that to remove win7 from dual boot I've to use live cd/usb, But I don't want to download 700MB+ again. Is there is any other way?

Comment: There are possibilities for hot deleting/resizing partitions but I would not advise it if you are not VERY familiar with partition tools like fdisk and mkfs. Plus if you have to move the beggining of your Linux partition, you will have to reboot on a liveCD.

Comment: What bootloader do you currently have installed? When you boot your computer, what is the screen you see to select the operating system to boot? Is it Grub (the purple one), or Windows? Also, post a screenshot of Gparted (download it using `sudo apt-get install gparted` and open it).

Comment: again? what did you download the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to download a live CD. You can do it from Ubuntu with Gparted software which can be found in software center. Just go to gparted after you've downloaded it and installed it. Delete the windows partitions which are usually ntfs file systems and go to the command line and run: `sudo update-grub` or `sudo update-burg` whichever one you use. It should only show you your linux partitions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution but to avoid such a big download you can use something like GpartedLive which is very easy to use and wheights 191MB as of today.

You can find it there : http://gparted.org/download.php

Another way around is to download a very lightweight distribution (50MB) and partition using the utilitaries available in this one (if any I am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Try this link - [How to remove Windows from Within Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows). Always back-up important data before doing anything like this!